# How to read request's body in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2

Hi everyone I am new using WSO2 ESB, here is the issue I made a integration project to learn but I have not been able to read the body of my request when I try I see this warning "Json Payload is empty"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV6Ub.png)

Here is how I am trying to read the body `<filter regex="[1-9]" source="json-eval($.test)">`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvwSE.png)

And finally here is my request, I already set the header `application/json`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpk48.png)

If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The request needs to be a POST to see the payload hit the ESB.
With GET it will just do a GET request without it.

Technically you can do GET with body but it's not a very common scenario.[1]

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Unusual+Scenarios+for+HTTP+Methods+in+REST#UnusualScenariosforHTTPMethodsinREST-UsingGETwithaBody

Answer (score 0):

That is because the GET method in wso2 does not allow the body payload. You can read in wso2 documentation:

> Typically, a GET request does not contain a body, and the ESB profile does not support these types of requests. **When it receives a GET request that contains a body, it drops the message body** (...)

From doc: [Using GET with a Body](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Using+REST+with+APIs#UsingRESTwithAPIs-UsingGETwithaBody)

Additional it is not good practice to do that, refer to this question: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

So you should use POST request.